# How is the ReactJS beta component being styled?

Tags: css, reactjs

I was looking at the code of the new [React beta documentation website](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/blob/main/src/components/LayoutHeader/Header.js) and I saw this code

```js
const ContainerWrapper = ({children}) => (
  <div
    css={{ <----------------------------------------------------
      backgroundColor: 'hsl(222, 14%, 10%)',
    }}>
    {children}
  </div>
);
```

I'm curious about how they're using css attribute here instead of style. Is this a new feature?

Comment: Frontend protip: [Never link "here"](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/links-should-never-say-click-here).

Comment: Remember that JSX is not HTML. That's not a "css attribute", it's a JS object property called "css" (you're actually looking at javascript that's been made to look pretty, but there is _nothing_ in the code you're looking at that is HTML or HTML attributes - which is fairly important to know when using React).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That website is built with gatsby and they are using `gatsby-plugin-glamor` plugin. It simply allows you to write CSS in JS inline. You can read more here: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-glamor/

Comment: For future reference, looking into `package.json` file can get you answers.

Answer (score 0):

The `css` attribute you're seeing is actually a feature of Emotion, a CSS-in-JS library that is being used here.

Emotion is a library that allows you to write CSS in your JavaScript code, using a syntax that is similar to CSS. The `css` attribute you're seeing is a way to use Emotion's CSS-in-JS syntax in React components.

When you use the `css` attribute in a React component, you're actually passing a CSS-in-JS object to Emotion's `css` function. This function takes the CSS-in-JS object and generates the corresponding CSS styles at runtime. Emotion then injects the generated CSS styles into the HTML document.

The reason why Emotion uses the `css` attribute instead of the style attribute is to avoid conflicts with the standard style attribute, which is used to define inline styles in React components. By using a different attribute name, Emotion can avoid accidentally overwriting any inline styles that may be defined using the style attribute.